# Javascript countdown Issue. Want to clearInterval every click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gLLvux07/

I am creating a countdown using javascript. its working fine when i click the button.

The issue is, 
if I click the button when countdown running, it will not start from 0.

I am trying to clear interval in the beginning of function, but not working.

HTML :

```
<style>
.container {
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:100px;
    border:2px solid #ddd;
}

.count {
    -webkit-transition: all 1;
    -moz-transition: all 1;
    transition: all 1;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="count">
        <div>0</div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" onclick="countdown();" value="Click Me" />
</div>
```

Javascript Code :

```
function countdown() {
    clearInterval();
    $(".container .count").html("<div>0</div>")

    for(i=1;i<25;i++){
        $(".container .count").append("<div>"+i+"</div>");
    }

    var count1 = 0;
    var topmove = -10; 

    counting = setInterval(function(){                              
        $(".container .count").css({'-webkit-transform': 'translateY('+topmove+'px)'});
            count1 = count1+1;
            topmove = topmove-10;

            if(count1>40) {
                 clearInterval(counting);
            }  
    },100); 
 }
```

Comment: `clearInterval` accept a parameter, your first call to this function does not provides one. Don't forget to use `var` keyword to declare variable (for `i` and `counting`). Also, you can use JSHint (http://www.jshint.com/) to detect potentials errors in your code

Comment: Note that instead of proprietary `-webkit-transform` you should use CSS `position: absolute;` and modify `top`.

Comment: @Tomalak : yes,It also working fine. but need to set relative position to container.

Comment: Just make the container `position: relative;` and it will start to work as desired. (`position: absolute;` always works against the closest ancestor that also has a `position`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearInterval` requires a parameter telling the script which countdown to stop. Try something like this:

```
var counting;
function countdown() {
    if (typeof counting === 'number') clearInterval(counting);
    $(".container .count").html("<div>0</div>")
    for(i=1;i<25;i++)
        $(".container .count").append("<div>"+i+"</div>");  
    var count1 = 0,
        topmove = -10;
    counting = setInterval(function(){
        $(".container .count").css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateY('+topmove+'px)'
        });

        count1 = count1+1;
        topmove = topmove-10;
        if (count1>40){
            clearInterval(counting);
        }
    },100);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just define `counting` in global scope & do `clearInterval(counting);` in starting of function itself. You are not passing parameters to `clearInterval`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/gLLvux07/1/)